# Потеря данных при возврате из рекурсивного метода

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static string[] findDocument(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo fi = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            foreach (var e in fi.GetDirectories())
            {
                findDocument(e.FullName);
            }

            foreach (var e in fi.GetFiles())
            {
                if (e.Name == "password.txt")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    list.Add(Convert.ToString(e));
                }
            }
            
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] directory = findDocument(@"C:\fa\test");
        Console.WriteLine("---");
        foreach (var e in directory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Метод находит два пути  и записывает их в список, а потом в массив
но после того как я получаю этот массив там уже 1 путь

Comment: У вас ошибка в рекурсии. Вы теряете результат вложенных вызовов. Попробуйте сделать в первом цикле вот так list.AddRange(findDocument(e.FullName));  я думаю так будет норм

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Подсказка: слишком непонятно называете переменные, ваш код очень сложно читать. Подумайте над тем, как это исправить, и найдите, как это делают опытные разработчики.